# Homebrew won't link gcc on Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I'm trying to install gfortran on my Mac running High Sierra. I ran `brew gcc` and it ran to completion but would not link.  Homebrew gave the message to type `brew link --overwrite gcc` When I tried this I get an error message that it could not symlink because directory is not writable. Brew will not accept the sudo command. Can someone tell me how to install gcc on a Mac?

Comment: Try running `brew doctor` and following the good doctor's advice.

Comment: Have you gone through the steps at https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html ?

Comment: i have done both. no luck.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste in the exact command and error message.

Comment: I followed a link to the GCC Wiki page. There were precomplied binaries for gfortran for Sierra. They were packaged as easily installed .dmg files. I tried this option and it worked. My code now runs!!

Comment: It sounds good that your problem is resolved.  Do you plan to self-answer the question, or will you delete it?

Comment: I thought I would self answer it in case others have same problem.  Do you have an opinion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked sources but couldn't find a solution to the Homebrew issue. Further research led me to the [Wiki page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS) for gfortran. The page contained pre-compiled binaries of gfortran for MacOS Sierra. These were packaged as .dmg files which are easy to load on Apple computers. I downloaded the file and installed it. This worked.